# Do you have to dispose of the SPWeb in the EventReceiver when using properties.OpenWeb()?

Tags: development, dispose

Does **properties.OpenWeb()** create a new **SPRequest** object or does it refer to the existing **SPWeb** object already there in the **properties** object? Should we manually  dispose of the **SPWeb** obtained in this manner?

Is the second line safer?

```
        SPWeb _web = properties.OpenWeb();
        SPWeb _web = properties.ListItem.ParentList.ParentWeb;
```

Comment: By the way, current SPDisposeCheck fails to detect this undisposed SPWeb scenario.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In SharePoint 2007 you need to dispose the returned SPWeb if you use properties.OpenWeb()

In SP2010 you should use the [SPItemEventProperties.Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.web(office.14).aspx) property instead. This performs better than OpenWeb and has no dispose issues.

hth
Anders Rask

Answer (score 0):

Should nobody prove me wrong, I shall presume (until I resort to ILDASM / Reflector) that the safe way in ItemEventReceivers would be to use

```
SPWeb _web = properties.ListItem.ParentList.ParentWeb;
```

Surely,

```
if (properties.ListItem != null) SPWeb _web = properties.ListItem.ParentList.ParentWeb;
```

or

```
bool _shouldDispose = false;
try {_web = properties.ListItem.ParentList.ParentWeb;} catch (SPException ex) {_web = properties.OpenWeb(); _shouldDispose=true;}
```

Comment: fyi, depending on the type of item event, properties.ListItem could be null (i.e. ItemDeleted)